# An interesting conjecture about the Laplace Transform

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, laplace-transform

I made an interesting observation about the Laplace transform that I think might pose a nice challenge, if hopefully there isn't anything obvious that I missed.

Recall the **final value theorem (FVT)** : $\forall f$ bounded on $(0,\infty)$ and such that $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}f(t)$ is finite,
$$\lim\limits_{s\to0^+}\left[s\mathcal{L}\left\lbrace f\right\rbrace(s)\right]=\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}f(t)$$
with $\displaystyle\mathcal{L}\left\lbrace f\right\rbrace(s)=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-st}f(t)dt$ the **Laplace transform** of $f$.

Now, I made the following observation :

> For a significant number of functions $f$, the limit
>   $$\lim\limits_{s\to0^+}\frac{s}{f\left(\frac{1}{s}\right)}\mathcal{L}\left\lbrace f\right\rbrace(s)$$
>   is finite.

We should note that, due to the FVT theorem stated above, it is obviously true when $f$ satisfies the above requirements for the FVT.

The thing is, this result, although weaker than the FVT when the FVT applies, seem to apply to a much wider range of function.

So far, I have tested it on polynomial functions, hyperbolic functions, exponential and logarithmic functions. This results *always seems to holds* whenever the function is continuous, and either **monotonically increasing and concave**, or **monotonically decreasing and convex** on $(0,\infty)$.

For instance, for $f:x\mapsto \sqrt{x}$ (which is neither bounded nor has a finite limit at $\infty$), the limit is $\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$ ; and for $f=\log_b$ for any base $b$ (including the natural log), the limit is $1$.
But, as metamorphy pointed out in a comment, it doesn't work for $f:x\mapsto e^{\sqrt{x}}$ : that's because this function is monotonically increasing but not concave on $(0,\infty)$.

So here's my conjecture :

> Show that $\forall f$ continuous, and either **monotonically increasing and concave**, or **monotonically decreasing and convex** on $(0,\infty)$,
>   $$\lim\limits_{s\to0^+}\frac{s}{f\left(\frac{1}{s}\right)}\mathcal{L}\left\lbrace f\right\rbrace(s)$$
>   is finite.

Wether or not the requirements for this result to holds are correct or not, I also wish to **find the value of this limit**.

I don't have a clue as how to proceed to tackle this. Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: You may want to change the limit to be $s\to 0^+$ otherwise this is not necessarily well defined even in the limited range of cases you've explicitly stated

Comment: $f(x)=e^{\sqrt{x}}$ is a counterexample. $\mathcal{L}\{f\}(s)\asymp\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{s^{3/2}}e^{1/(4s)}$ for $s\to 0^{+}$.

Comment: You are right, and after further investigation, if we add another requirement (in addition to continuity and monotony), the result seems to hold strong. See my edit.